# What does following linux script mean in page 70 of book "Design Data intensive applications" by Martin Kleppmann?

Tags: bash, sed

```
#!/bin/bash
    db_set () {
        echo "$1,$2" >> database
}
    db_get () {
        grep "^$1," database | sed -e "s/^$1,//" | tail -n 1
}
```

What does db_get() do?
Especially "sed -e "s/^$1,//""

Comment: That's not a "linux script". Please read the description of the tags you apply. Also, which parts are giving you problems to understand? As a new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

`db_get()` prints the last value for the key `$1`.
`$1`,`$2` are arguments to the script e.g. `1=money`, `2=34`.
`grep "^$1," database` lists all lines starting with `$1`.
`sed -e "s/^$1,//"` then removes the `key,` part, so that only the values remain.
`tail -n 1` prints only the last line.

You can try this out by yourself with e.g.

```
$ cat database
jack,5
gill,6
jack,3
$ key=jack
$ grep "^$key," database
jack,5
jack,3
$ grep "^$key," database | sed -e "s/^$key,//"
5
3
$ grep "^$key," database | sed -e "s/^$key,//" | tail -n 1
3
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this is really helpful!